# Cannot connect to mosquitto 2.0 with paho library

Tags: go, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I cannot seem to connect to the mosquitto 2.0 broker from the paho library ("github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/paho") for golang.  Can anyone point out the error of my ways?

I took the connect logic from the [paho chat example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/blob/master/paho/cmd/chat/main.go) and attempted to connect to my localhost server, but got reason code 135 (not authorised).  I then attempted to connect to the mosquitto server with mosquitto_pub, with success.  I used the same username and password for both cases.  The mosquitto log output is below:

```
1608068903: New connection from 127.0.0.1:58794 on port 1883.
1608068903: Client <unknown> disconnected, not authorised.
1608069349: New connection from 127.0.0.1:58908 on port 1883.
1608069349: New client connected from 127.0.0.1:58908 as test (p5, c1, k60, u'username').
```

The mosquitto_pub command I'm using is:

```
snap run mosquitto.pub -h localhost -t hello -u username -P password -m hello -V mqttv5 -i test
```

The golang code is:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/paho"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "net"
)

func Test() {
    conn, err := net.Dial("tcp", "localhost:1883")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to %s: %s", "localhost", err)
    }
    c := paho.NewClient(paho.ClientConfig{
        Router: paho.NewSingleHandlerRouter(func(m *paho.Publish) {
            log.Printf("%s : %s", m.Properties.User["chatname"], string(m.Payload))
        }),
        Conn: conn,
    })

    username := "username"
    password := "password"

    cp := &paho.Connect{
        KeepAlive:  30,
        ClientID:   "test",
        CleanStart: false,
        Username:   username,
        Password:   []byte(password),
    }
    ca, err := c.Connect(context.Background(), cp)
    if ca.ReasonCode != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to %s : %d - %s", "localhost", ca.ReasonCode, ca.Properties.ReasonString)
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Connected to %s\n", "localhost")

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `UsernameFlag` and `PasswordFlag` to `paho.Connect` e.g.:

```
cp := &paho.Connect{
        KeepAlive:  30,
        ClientID:   "test",
        CleanStart: false,
        Username:   username,
        UsernameFlag: true,
        Password:   []byte(password),
        PasswordFlag: true,
    }
```

The `paho.golang` documentation needs work but this is covered in the [mqtt v5 spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc385349235). I have tested this with Mosquitto 2.0.1  and connected successfully.

Comment: That's interesting, why have four fields for username and password in the client API?

Comment: My understanding is that this client is aiming to be fairly low level and implement the MQTT v5 spec in an unopinionated way (avoiding some of the issues in the v3.1 package). Note that feedback is welcome; please raise an issue with your experiences/comments (one of the main reasons this has not reached v1 is a lack of feedback).